# The installation directory "/root" is not writable - Error when install Drush

Tags: drush, ssh

i want to install drush on my server .

I want to install drush-toolbox project globaly on my linux server box so all users can use it

My server: Cpanel , Litespeed , Cagefs , Cloudlinux (centos 6)

my drupal version 7.5x

I try this article [CLick here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2366283) and after run this command:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

I get this error :
**The installation directory "/root" is not writable**

I run this command : `chmod 640 /root` and `chmod 644 /root`  but give same error (not writable)

Please help me.Is any guidance for me?

Comment: `php -m` _I not see any module called "drush"_. That is normal. Drush is not a php module. It is a standalone php package that requires php to run. Not an extension on php.

Comment: but when I run drush commands have no any result.how i can test install drush is correctly?

Comment: Please Help me for Install Drush on my linux server with cloudlinux and LSWS.

Comment: I give "/root directory is not writable" when drush composer want to be installed by php.please help me.

Comment: If you tried to chmod the root folder I suggest you first learn some linux Server maintenance tutorials or something...

Comment: ok!! So for solve this problem (php can't install drush composer on /root folder) what I must do ?

Answer (score 1):

The composer method for installing drush works, but is outdated. Use the drush documentation for the right instructions: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

```
# Download latest stable release using the code below or browse to github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases.
php -r "readfile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush
# Or use our upcoming release: php -r "readfile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.drush.org/drush-unstable.phar');" > drush

# Test your install.
php drush core-status

# Make `drush` executable as a command from anywhere. Destination can be anywhere on $PATH.
chmod +x drush
sudo mv drush /usr/local/bin

# Optional. Enrich the bash startup file with completion and aliases.
drush init
```

Comment: thank you,I tried this manual previously but it was unsuccesssful.I tried this again.after every command line which i send no have any results.this is my command: `-bash-4.1# php -r "readfile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > drush
-bash-4.1# php drush core-status
-bash-4.1# chmod +x drush
-bash-4.1# sudo mv drush /usr/local/bin
-bash-4.1# drush init
-bash: /root/drush/drush: No such file or directory
-bash-4.1# drush init
-bash: /root/drush/drush: No such file or directory
-bash-4.1#
`

Comment: Try opening a new Shell after moving the file.

Comment: I am not a proffessional in linux management.You can help me by write codes and steps here?

Comment: Close the Shell or SSH connection and open it again

Comment: I retype steps code and after first command and mv command close and reopen ssh , but `php drush core-status` have no any results and `drush init` command give me this error : ** `/root/drush/drush: No such file or directory `** . @Neograph734 thank you for your asnwers

Comment: I cant install drush on my server successfully yet ! :(

Comment: I don't know. Sorry